# How to find group differences with irregularly measured, nested, and missing data?

Tags: spss, missing-data, group-differences

**Background:** I have a dataset, which consists of waterlevel measurements over time at different locations. However, the locations are irregularly measured in different years. Therefore my data consists of more gaps than actual data. 
Additionally, some of my data is nested. That means that some of my measurements can be grouped under another measurement, while others are not.

**How can I best test whether there is a difference between the waterlevels of various locations given these features of the data?**

Comment: Just for my learning, how is the data nested? By location (i.e. multiple water levels around a lake)?

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely a job for multilevel models (aka hierarchical models, mixed models and other terms). It's a big field, but the essential idea is to deal with non-independent data, which you have, certainly in terms of time and possibly place as well.

There are tools for this in SAS (PROC MIXED, NLMIXED or GLIMMIX, you probably want MIXED) and R (a couple of packages, such as nlme).

Comment: ...and in Stata too! (`xtmixed`, `xtlogit`, `xtpoisson`...)

Comment: It sounds like the dependence structure is a nuisance and primary interest focuses on differences in means. Is there a particular reason you're suggesting random effects models rather than something like GEE which has the nice property of consistency of regression coefficient estimates even when the association structure is misspecified?

Comment: @macro In general, I find mixed models more intuitive, perhaps just because I am more used to them. You're right that GEE could be good here.

Comment: @Macro: I'd suggest giving your comment as a separate answer. I, too, know little about GEE's, except that they address population means when there are various correlation issues.

Comment: @PeterFlom: R's `lme4` package is more intuitive for me, but not as flexible in regard to correlation structure. (I like `lme4` a lot, but I'm just a rookie at this and don't have a firm grasp on the correlation part: just parroting what "they" say.)

Comment: @Wayne I find SAS PROC MIXED much more intuitive than either R package, but that may be just because I am used to it.

Comment: @PeterFlom: Sorry, I meant of the R packages. SAS' options may be better, I simply don't have access to SAS, and as an ex-programmer, programs whose syntax was designed for punched cards in the 1970's make me break out in hives.